# Passing Data from Dropbox Chooser to controller/model in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, dropbox, dropbox-api

EDIT:

I am getting the JSON results from the dropbox chooser, but they are not being parsed properly to be put into the database. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, if I should be doing a JSON decoder in my controller or if it is something else.

Controller Code:

```
<?php class DropboxfilesController extends AppController {
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->File->create();
    if ($this->File->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your file is now available :)'));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Something went wrong!'));
    }
}
}}?>
```

View Code:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('File'); ?>
<input type="Dropboxfilechooser" name="selected-file" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Finish'); ?>
```

Model Code:

```
<?php class File extends AppModel {}?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to process file uploads without CakePHP?

Comment: I've done it before procedurally, I've just started to learn OOP and this framework. To be a little more clear, I'm not trying to "upload" a file, I'm trying to store a link to a file.

Comment: Really looking into parsing the response from dropbox containing the link, thumbnail, icon and bytes and store that in a table (using their chooser tool).

Comment: does the chooser appear to work on the front end to begin with? the docs use: <input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" style="visibility: hidden;"/> i.e., it looks like you've changed the "type" here. if/when it is working, it should just submit the link as a normal value in the form under "selected-file".

Comment: It is getting the link, I am able to get the link procedural but now that I am doing it object-oriented I am unable to get the links. Am I missing something in the model or the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is looking at the source code, the form action is not going to the proper controller, it is just going to the cake/homes. Just change that and the problem is solved.